# How can I remove these packages with unmet dependencies when I get dpkg error "trying to overwrite... which is also in..."?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. Some months ago I tried to install nvdia drivers, but I couldn't, the installation didn't complete properly, and apt-get get broken. Since I had to finish somework, I keep this problem aside and just finished my work. Now I want to solve those problems, but I don't remember which steps did I exactly take.

My goal is to remove everything related to nvidia drivers, cuda and this stuff and start again from scratch (or  maybe not use it anymore but I must be able to use apt-get).

Now, whatever I run with `apt-get`, I get `E: Unmet dependencies`, for example:

```
sudo apt-get remove htop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-396 : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-396-dev : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-opencl-icd-396 : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

As suggested by the output, I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and get this:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-20 linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-396
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-396
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 88 not upgraded.
158 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/80,0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 328 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-local  nvidia-396 396.37-0ubuntu1 [80,0 MB]
(Reading database ... 239091 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-396_396.37-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-396 (396.37-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-9-2-local/./nvidia-396_396.37-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0', which is also in package libglx-mesa0:amd64 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-9-2-local/./nvidia-396_396.37-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried some suggested commands, but with same result:

```
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not installed
 libcuda1-396 : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not installed
 nvidia-396-dev : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not installed
 nvidia-opencl-icd-396 : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also run sudo apt-get clean and sudo apt-get autoclean. The first didn't have an output, the second show that:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

But the problem persists.

I also tried to remove them with `apt-get purge`, but get this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-396-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-396-dev (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-396 : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-opencl-icd-396 : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I also run `sudo apt-get -f install` that showed:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-20 linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-396
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-396
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 88 not upgraded.
158 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/80,0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 328 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-local  nvidia-396 396.37-0ubuntu1 [80,0 MB]
(Reading database ... 239091 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-396_396.37-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-396 (396.37-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-9-2-local/./nvidia-396_396.37-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0', which is also in package libglx-mesa0:amd64 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-9-2-local/./nvidia-396_396.37-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And finally I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a`:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libvulkan1:amd64 (1.1.70+dfsg1-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-xinerama0:amd64 (1.13-1) ...
Setting up libx11-xcb-dev:amd64 (2:1.6.4-3) ...
Setting up x11proto-dri2-dev (2018.4-4) ...
Setting up libopengl0:amd64 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up freeglut3:amd64 (2.8.1-3) ...
Setting up libusageenvironment3:amd64 (2018.02.18-1) ...
Setting up libplacebo4:amd64 (0.4.0-2) ...
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.8.8) ...
Setting up libdouble-conversion1:amd64 (2.0.1-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-396-dev:
 nvidia-396-dev depends on nvidia-396 (>= 396.37); however:
  Package nvidia-396 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-396-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libxshmfence-dev:amd64 (1.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Setting up vlc-data (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libdvbpsi10:amd64 (1.3.2-1) ...
Setting up libmpcdec6:amd64 (2:0.1~r495-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-opencl-icd-396:
 nvidia-opencl-icd-396 depends on nvidia-396 (>= 396.37); however:
  Package nvidia-396 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-opencl-icd-396 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libaribb24-0:amd64 (1.0.3-1) ...
Setting up libbasicusageenvironment1:amd64 (2018.02.18-1) ...
Setting up libproxy-tools (0.4.15-1) ...
Setting up libmicrodns0:amd64 (0.0.8-1) ...
Setting up libdrm-dev:amd64 (2.4.91-2) ...
Setting up libxmu-headers (2:1.1.2-2) ...
Setting up x11proto-fixes-dev (1:2018.4-4) ...
Setting up libebml4v5:amd64 (1.3.5-2) ...
Setting up java-common (0.63ubuntu1~02) ...
Setting up libfaad2:amd64 (2.8.8-1) ...
Setting up libkate1:amd64 (0.4.1-7build1) ...
Setting up libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15+dfsg2-0.1) ...
Setting up libdc1394-22:amd64 (2.2.5-1) ...
Setting up x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev (2018.4-4) ...
Setting up libgif7:amd64 (5.1.4-2) ...
Setting up libc6-i386 (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-license-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
*** LICENSE AGREEMENT ***
By using this software you agree to fully comply with the terms and 
conditions of the EULA (End User License Agreement). The EULA is located
at /usr/local/cuda-9.2/doc/EULA.txt. The EULA can also be found at
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/eula/index.html. If you do not agree to the
terms and conditions of the EULA, do not use the software.

Setting up vlc-l10n (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libnfs11:amd64 (2.0.0-1~exp1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvprune-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-dri2-0-dev:amd64 (1.13-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-render0-dev:amd64 (1.13-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers:
 cuda-drivers depends on nvidia-396 (>= 396.37); however:
  Package nvidia-396 is not installed.
 cuda-drivers depends on nvidia-396-dev (>= 396.37); however:
  Package nvidia-396-dev is not configured yet.
 cuda-drivers depends on nvidia-opencl-icd-396 (>= 396.37); however:
  Package nvidia-opencl-icd-396 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up x11proto-damage-dev (1:2018.4-4) ...
Setting up libxcb-dri3-dev:amd64 (1.13-1) ...
Setting up libssh2-1:amd64 (1.8.0-1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libupnp6:amd64 (1:1.6.24-4) ...
Setting up libvlccore9:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up cuda-cudart-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-video-splitter:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up qttranslations5-l10n (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up screen-resolution-extra (0.17.3) ...
Setting up libcddb2 (1.3.2-5fakesync1) ...
Setting up x11proto-gl-dev (2018.4-4) ...
Setting up nvidia-modprobe (396.37-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvprof-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvrtc-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-shape0-dev:amd64 (1.13-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvtx-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libgroupsock8:amd64 (2018.02.18-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-glx0-dev:amd64 (1.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-visualization:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up liblua5.2-0:amd64 (5.2.4-1.1build1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-runtime-9-2:
 cuda-runtime-9-2 depends on cuda-drivers (>= 396.37); however:
  Package cuda-drivers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-runtime-9-2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libsdl-image1.2:amd64 (1.2.12-8) ...
Setting up ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 (2.2.11-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libmad0:amd64 (0.15.1b-8ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-notify:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libresid-builder0c2a (2.1.1-15ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsidplay2 (2.1.1-15ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libdca0:amd64 (0.0.5-10) ...
Setting up libsndio6.1:amd64 (1.1.0-3) ...
Setting up liblivemedia62:amd64 (2018.02.18-1) ...
Setting up cuda-cusolver-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up fonts-dejavu-extra (2.37-1) ...
Setting up libxxf86vm-dev:amd64 (1:1.1.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20180409) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Setting up libprotobuf-lite10:amd64 (3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libatk-wrapper-java (0.33.3-20ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libxfixes-dev:amd64 (1:5.0.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Setting up libopenmpt-modplug1:amd64 (0.3.6-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvml-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libglvnd-core-dev:amd64 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up x11proto-input-dev (2018.4-4) ...
Setting up libxnvctrl0 (396.37-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-cufft-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-sync-dev:amd64 (1.13-1) ...
Setting up lib32gcc1 (1:8-20180414-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.12.6-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcuda1-396:
 libcuda1-396 depends on nvidia-396 (>= 396.37); however:
  Package nvidia-396 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libcuda1-396 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cuda-npp-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-misc-headers-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-memcheck-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-randr0-dev:amd64 (1.13-1) ...
Setting up cuda-npp-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libqt5dbus5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvdisasm-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libmatroska6v5:amd64 (1.4.8-1.1) ...
Setting up libvlc5:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libqt5network5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-driver-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up mesa-common-dev:amd64 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-samba:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up cuda-curand-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-cusolver-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libxmu-dev:amd64 (2:1.1.2-2) ...
Setting up libxcb-xfixes0-dev:amd64 (1.13-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-9-2:
 cuda-9-2 depends on cuda-runtime-9-2 (>= 9.2.148); however:
  Package cuda-runtime-9-2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-9-2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cuda-cublas-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-demo-suite-9-2:
 cuda-demo-suite-9-2 depends on cuda-runtime-9-2; however:
  Package cuda-runtime-9-2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-demo-suite-9-2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libxdamage-dev:amd64 (1:1.1.4-3) ...
Setting up cuda-cuobjdump-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-cusparse-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvgraph-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-gpu-library-advisor-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libglvnd-dev:amd64 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-settings (396.37-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-gdb-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-video-output:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libatk-wrapper-java-jni:amd64 (0.33.3-20ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up cuda-cudart-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-cufft-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libvlc-bin:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda:
 cuda depends on cuda-9-2 (>= 9.2.148); however:
  Package cuda-9-2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libqt5gui5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-libraries-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-cusparse-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-present-dev:amd64 (1.13-1) ...
Setting up libxi-dev:amd64 (2:1.7.9-1) ...
Setting up qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvcc-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-cupti-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-cublas-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-base:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up vlc-bin (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up cuda-command-line-tools-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-curand-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libqt5x11extras5:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libqt5widgets5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-compiler-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libqt5svg5:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-libraries-dev-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 (9.0.0-2.1build1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-qt:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-skins2:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up freeglut3-dev:amd64 (2.8.1-3) ...
Setting up cuda-samples-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-documentation-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up vlc (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (10.0.1+10-3ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmid to provide /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool to provide /usr/bin/keytool (keytool) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jjs to provide /usr/bin/jjs (jjs) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/pack200 to provide /usr/bin/pack200 (pack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmiregistry to provide /usr/bin/rmiregistry (rmiregistry) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/unpack200 to provide /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/orbd to provide /usr/bin/orbd (orbd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/servertool to provide /usr/bin/servertool (servertool) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/tnameserv to provide /usr/bin/tnameserv (tnameserv) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jexec to provide /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) in auto mode
Setting up default-jre-headless (2:1.10-63ubuntu1~02) ...
Setting up openjdk-11-jre:amd64 (10.0.1+10-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20170930ubuntu1) ...
Adding debian:Certplus_Root_CA_G2.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_EV_2009.pem
Adding debian:EE_Certification_Centre_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Izenpe.com.pem
Adding debian:AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.pem
Adding debian:SwissSign_Gold_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Buypass_Class_3_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_3.pem
Adding debian:Trustis_FPS_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:IdenTrust_Public_Sector_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:Visa_eCommerce_Root.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:ISRG_Root_X1.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Taiwan_GRCA.pem
Adding debian:LuxTrust_Global_Root_2.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Universal_CA.pem
Adding debian:Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem
Adding debian:CFCA_EV_ROOT.pem
Adding debian:USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem
Adding debian:Deutsche_Telekom_Root_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Certinomis_-_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_1_G3.pem
Adding debian:SZAFIR_ROOT_CA2.pem
Adding debian:TrustCor_RootCert_CA-1.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R5.pem
Adding debian:TeliaSonera_Root_CA_v1.pem
Adding debian:Secure_Global_CA.pem
Adding debian:USERTrust_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Global_Chambersign_Root_-_2008.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:Certplus_Root_CA_G1.pem
Adding debian:Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
Adding debian:OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GB_CA.pem
Adding debian:Certum_Trusted_Network_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:TrustCor_RootCert_CA-2.pem
Adding debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_EV_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:DST_Root_CA_X3.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_EC1.pem
Adding debian:TrustCor_ECA-1.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_2.pem
Adding debian:AddTrust_External_Root.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.pem
Adding debian:thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068.pem
Adding debian:Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:TWCA_Global_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GA_CA.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_3.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Universal_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:OpenTrust_Root_CA_G2.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Class_2_CA.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:TWCA_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G4.pem
Adding debian:SecureTrust_CA.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Networking.pem
Adding debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_ECC_RootCA_2015.pem
Adding debian:Buypass_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Premium_ECC.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_3.pem
Adding debian:Network_Solutions_Certificate_Authority.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Premium.pem
Adding debian:TÜRKTRUST_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı_H5.pem
Adding debian:thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:VeriSign_Universal_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Trusted_Root_G4.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G2.pem
Adding debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2015.pem
Adding debian:thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R4.pem
Adding debian:Atos_TrustedRoot_2011.pem
Adding debian:E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:CA_Disig_Root_R2.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
Adding debian:Certum_Trusted_Network_CA.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.pem
Adding debian:VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Services_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:SwissSign_Silver_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:XRamp_Global_CA_Root.pem
Adding debian:SecureSign_RootCA11.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G3.pem
Adding debian:ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Comodo_AAA_Services_root.pem
Adding debian:Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA_2009.pem
Adding debian:Chambers_of_Commerce_Root_-_2008.pem
Adding debian:Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2011.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:EC-ACC.pem
Adding debian:certSIGN_ROOT_CA.pem
Adding debian:TUBITAK_Kamu_SM_SSL_Kok_Sertifikasi_-_Surum_1.pem
Adding debian:Cybertrust_Global_Root.pem
Adding debian:OpenTrust_Root_CA_G3.pem
Adding debian:Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_4.pem
Adding debian:Certplus_Class_2_Primary_CA.pem
Adding debian:ACCVRAIZ1.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA_R2.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:GDCA_TrustAUTH_R5_ROOT.pem
Adding debian:ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_2_G3.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_RootCA2.pem
Adding debian:D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_2009.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R3.pem
Adding debian:Certigna.pem
Adding debian:OpenTrust_Root_CA_G1.pem
done.
Setting up default-jre (2:1.10-63ubuntu1~02) ...
Setting up cuda-nsight-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvvp-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-visual-tools-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-tools-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Setting up cuda-toolkit-9-2 (9.2.148-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libvlc-bin:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20180409) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-396-dev
 nvidia-opencl-icd-396
 cuda-drivers
 cuda-runtime-9-2
 libcuda1-396
 cuda-9-2
 cuda-demo-suite-9-2
 cuda
```

And I also tried to remove them one by one with `apt-get remove --dry-run`:

```
sudo apt-get remove --dry-run cuda-runtime-9-2 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-9-2 : Depends: cuda-runtime-9-2 (>= 9.2.148) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-demo-suite-9-2 : Depends: cuda-runtime-9-2 but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-396 : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-396-dev : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-opencl-icd-396 : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.37) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also read soma answers that sugggested using  `Synaptic Package Manager`, but I don't have it installed and I can't install it since `apt-get` is not working...

any ideas?

thanks